# Books = await _db.Book.ToListAsync(); using directive "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;" does not appear when I ctl dot "ToListAsync"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RazorBooks.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


namespace RazorBooks.Pages.BookList
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel//code to populate Index Page with books
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public async Task OnGet()
        {
            Books = await _db.Book.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Like I say I am really new.  I am just trying to show a list of values in the html page using VS19 but the ToListAsync "using" does not work on the C# page.

Comment: I don't know if I understood it right, but it seems you need to add an: `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` in your code.

Comment: ToListAsync returns a task not a lit. You need to do something like this:

var Books0 = await _db.Book.ToListAsync();
Books = Books0.Select(.....)

Comment: The code fix to add a `using` directive for extension methods sometimes does not work, sometimes this is a missing package reference, other times it isn't clear why. Things in this area have changed in VS2019 update 1 with the addition of "IntelliCode" for C# so likely some behaviours are changing.